What is the default `datetime.now()` timezone?
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timezone

print(f'datetime.now(): {datetime.now()}')
print(f'current timezone: {datetime.now().tzinfo}') # prints `None`

As seen in the above code snippet, the default timezone for a datetime object created with datetime.now() is None.
My question is how to interpret this?
No explicit timezone is set, however the value produced by datetime.now() matches the value of the system clock of the server on which this code was run.
This implies the timezone is actually the same as the system timezone, in this case, at the time of writing, BST.
Why does datetime.now() not set a timezone? I would like to know more detail about the internal working of datetime which might explain the behaviour. It seems surprising.

It's using the current value of your local clock, but does not embed timezone information. So the resulting datetime object has no timezone (is "naïve").

See this answer: Answer to How do I get a value of datetime.today() in Python that is "timezone aware"?

Mind that datetime.today() and datetime.now() return the local time, not the UTC time

So from my understanding, datetime.now() returns the time local to you / the user of your program - the time shown by the clock in the corner of your screen.

@DylanRogers that linked answer is outdated. Should be this one.

two additional remarks; (1) with .astimezone(None) you can get aware datetime with your current UTC offset, without explicitly setting a time zone (example). (2) with naive datetime in Python, be careful with the .timestamp() method; it will convert the datetime to UTC as if it was aware before calculating Unix time.

For a very long time Python didn't include any tzinfo classes, so it was impossible for it to deliver a timezone aware object.  Even today it's difficult for it to know which time zone to use unless you explicitly tell it.

@FObersteiner Thanks, the answer I posted is still valid I think, but thanks for the updated one :)

Thanks for the responses. Can anyone say anything about how timezone information works within a datetime object? For example, if the local time is 10:00, and the system clock is set to track the BST timezone, then if I explicitly set the timezone to UTC with datetime.now(timezone.utc), then the returned time value will be 09:00. My question really relates to this. What does Python do to add the timezone information and how does it figure out that it needs to subtract 1 hour from the local time reported by the system clock.

I should add - I understand how the System Clock tracks time. It uses NTP. If I understand correctly, this makes request to a centralized server periodically to "ask" what is the current time. It then sets the system clock value (which I believe is actually implemented in hardware). But what is important is that the system clock does not have any knowledge of timezone. The Operating System might know what timezone it is in? Does datetime make a system call to get this information, perhaps?

Assume that the operating system knows what time it is, locally and globally and timezone aware. When you do datetime.now(timezone.utc), Python will provide you the correct current UTC time, ultimately stemming from operating system time keeping infrastructure somewhere. How exactly that works may depend on the exact system, but it’s pretty sure to work on any modern system Python runs on.

To add some details, if you have naive datetime in Python, it uses the system's C library (e.g. what is defined in time.h) to obtain UTC offset information for example. This is also used by strptime/strftime btw., which is why results are platform-specific. On top of that, you can use the zoneinfo Python module to access your system's timezone database and generate tzinfo objects (which hold the tz information for the datetime). While this is implemented in Python (3.9+), it is still system-dependent (unless you're on Windows and have to add the tzdata package).
